# Passing QVector<float> from worker thread to main thread via signal/slot

Tags: multithreading, qt, signals-slots, qthread

Currently I have some troubles passing a QVector between to threads. At the moment I have a main thread (GUI-Thread) and an worker thread that emits frequently QVector arrays. Directly before emitting the data inside the vector looks good. The receiver is a slot in the main thread but the Data received in by the slot is garbled.

Here are some parts of my code:

Emit in the worker thread:

```
void Pipeline::process
{
    QVector<float> buffer(w * h * d);

    // filling the vector with RGB-Values

    emit this->pushBuffer(buffer, w, h, d);
}
```

Connection of signal and slot in the main thread:

```
QObject::connect(this->_pipeline.data(), SIGNAL(pushBuffer(const QVector<float>, int, int, int)), this->ui->widgetFiltered, SLOT(setBuffer(const QVector<float>,int,int,int)));
```

Slot in the main thread:

```
void GLWidget::setBuffer(const QVector<float> buffer, int dataSizeX, int dataSizeY, int dataSizeZ)
{
    // at this point the contents inside 'buffer' is garbled
}
```

The Thread is started by using QObject's moveToThread and `QVector<float>` registered to the meta-system by `qRegisterMetaType< QVector<float> >("QVector<float>");` in the main method.

Is it possible that the data gets lost after `Pipeline::process` returns? I am not sure how the implicit sharing inside `QVector`behaves in this multi-threaded case.

Any help would be appreciated.

Greetings

Wolf

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a) Register metatype QVector. Add this line before `app.exec()` in your main function:

```
qRegisterMetaType<QVector<float> >("QVector<float>");
```

Without this QueuedConnection won't work.

b) explicitly say that your signal and slot connected via `Qt::QueuedConnection`
if you do moveToThread after connect, this should fix slot execution in proper thread.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I already have a `qRegisterMetaType<QVector<float> >("QVector<float>")`in my main function, I just forgot to post it. I have added the `Qt::QueuedConnection` just as you said but it is still garbled :-(.

Comment: Strange - qt copies data if queued connection used, so you should have copy of vector even if you went out of scope... Are you sure vector contains proper data before emit, and nothing else in your code don't breaks memory?

Comment: Hmm, I just figured out that without linking vtk into my project this connection works fine. Very very strange ... :-D.